# How does try-catch works in IL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, cil

Consider this code:

```
void Main()
{
    try {
        Console.Write("try ");
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
    catch (NotImplementedException) {
        Console.Write("catch");
    }
}
```

Using LINQPad, I see the code compiles to:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  nop         
IL_0002:  ldstr       "try"
IL_0007:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_000C:  nop         
IL_000D:  newobj      System.NotImplementedException..ctor
IL_0012:  throw       
IL_0013:  pop         
IL_0014:  nop         
IL_0015:  ldstr       "catch"
IL_001A:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_001F:  nop         
IL_0020:  nop         
IL_0021:  leave.s
```

The code above prints `try catch`, if I throw `Exception` instead, `try` is printed and the program exits due to the unhandled exception (as expected), the *IL* code remains the same, except this line:

```
IL_000D:  newobj      System.Exception..ctor
```

What is the logic behind that? 
I would except for logic that checks the type of the exception to make a decision if to go into the catch block or not.

Comment: Exception handling in IL is *table based* - somewhere else (can't tell you if LINQPad would show it) there'll be a table saying "for exceptions thrown between *this* instruction and *that* instruction, *these* are the handlers to use.

Comment: LINQPad isn't showing you the full decompilation, just the instruction sequence. My LINQPad says "Press Alt+Shift+R for a full decompilation", which opens up ILSpy, which does include the information on the exception blocks (when you switch to IL).

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I do see the full IL code now.
So if I get it right, the IL code contains an IL try and a catch as well, the the CLR handles these?

I will read more about the _table based_ exception handling, thanks.

Comment: The IL contains the tables that say where the exception blocks begin and end, in the same way they contain metadata on the number and type of parameters in a method. ILSpy translates these to `.try/catch/finally` blocks (of the kind that an IL assembler would accept); they are part of the metadata, but not IL instructions themselves, so a naive disassembly like that of LINQPad doesn't show them.

Comment: You can get this table at runtime using reflection: the `MethodBody.ExceptionHandlingClauses` property is a `IList<ExceptionHandlingClause>` containing the entries of the mentioned table. You can find a few words about that in the msdn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.exceptionhandlingclause?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

I little bit of necromancy here. I've spent several hours reading specs on the subject and here are some interesting details that aren't covered in comments.
The quotes are taken from [Standard ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/):

> Each method in an executable has associated with it a (possibly empty) array of exception
> handling information. Each entry in the array describes a protected block, its filter, and its
> handler.
> When an exception occurs, the CLI searches the array for the first protected block that

- Protects a region including the current instruction pointer and
- Whose filter wishes to handle the exception

> If a match is not found in the current method, the calling method is searched, and so on. If no
> match is found the CLI will dump a stack trace and abort the program

Some things to notice are:

- Exception handlers can access the local variables and the local memory pool of the
  routine that catches the exception, but any intermediate results on the evaluation stack
  at the time the exception was thrown are lost
- An exception object describing the exception is automatically created by the CLI and
  pushed onto the evaluation stack as the first item upon entry of a filter or catch clause

So that "a (possibly empty) array of exception handling information" is actually a section that every method has

> At the next 4-byte boundary following the method body can be extra method data sections. Currently, the method data sections are only used for exception tables.

And that section consists of `clauses` which store information about where `try` block starts, where it ends, where `catch` starts and there is one particular field — `ClassToken` which is described as `Meta data token for a type-based exception handler` which should be the information about exception type that could be handled by that particular catch block.

Unfortunately, ILDASM doesn't show raw method headers and inserts information from there as `.try` instructions in disassembled code view, but the IL itself has no specific instructions for exception type handling as it does not inserts specific intermediate code for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand a bit on the last point from cassandrad's answer:

> but the IL itself has no specific instructions for exception type handling as it does not inserts specific intermediate code for the same purpose.

This is true and what OP's question was about

> Unfortunately, ILDASM doesn't show raw method headers and inserts information from there as .try instructions in disassembled code view,

If you use ILDasm with the UI from .NET Framework SDK, it has the option to "expand try/catch" to make it look like it is in the IL.

This is the IL for OP's example with expanded try/catch that may make you think that try/catch are somehow part of the IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       36 (0x24)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  nop
    IL_0002:  ldstr      "try "
    IL_0007:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::Write(string)
    IL_000c:  nop
    IL_000d:  newobj     instance void [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor()
    IL_0012:  throw
  }  // end .try
  catch [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException 
  {
    IL_0013:  pop
    IL_0014:  nop
    IL_0015:  ldstr      "catch"
    IL_001a:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::Write(string)
    IL_001f:  nop
    IL_0020:  nop
    IL_0021:  leave.s    IL_0023
  }  // end handler
  IL_0023:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

(You would get the same IL if you use ILSpy)

But if you turn off the try/catch expansion (annotation in the IL code).

[image]

you get this version:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       36 (0x24)
  .maxstack  1
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  nop
  IL_0002:  ldstr      "try "
  IL_0007:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::Write(string)
  IL_000c:  nop
  IL_000d:  newobj     instance void [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException::.ctor()
  IL_0012:  throw
  IL_0013:  pop
  IL_0014:  nop
  IL_0015:  ldstr      "catch"
  IL_001a:  call       void [System.Console]System.Console::Write(string)
  IL_001f:  nop
  IL_0020:  nop
  IL_0021:  leave.s    IL_0023
  IL_0023:  ret
  IL_0024:  
  // Exception count 1
  .try IL_0001 to IL_0013 catch [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException handler IL_0013 to IL_0023
} // end of method Program::Main
```

This is closer to reality where IL is just IL and the try-catch blocks are defined at the end of method as clauses that help the CLR know which regions of the IL are in a try block and which regions handle exceptions for those blocks.

This is the syntax for those clauses that I managed to get from the excellent book by Serge Lidin - .NET IL Assembler (2014).

```
.try <label> to <label> <EH_type_specific> handler <label> to <label>
```

In our example this is:

```
.try IL_0001 to IL_0013 catch [System.Runtime]System.NotImplementedException handler IL_0013 to IL_0023
```